# A good example of using the Mapbox distance API

Tags: mapbox

I am trying to use Mapbox to calculate the duration between two locations however the examples [here](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=JavaScript#distance) are incomplete (at least with my limited experience). I would like to connect to this API using server-side Java, however I can't even get a basic example working in javaScript, Python or simply in the address bar in my browser.

I can get an example working in my browser using this url and substituting in my API key:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/Chester.json?country=us&access_token=pk.my-token-value
```

However I can't get a similar example working with the distance API. The best I can manage is something like this:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/distances/v1/driving/[13.41894,52.50055],[14.10293,52.50055]&access_token=pk.my-token-value.
```

But I have no idea how to format my coordinates as I can't find a single example.

Has anyone been able to get this working. Ideally in Java, but client-side JavaScript or a valid url would be a great start.

I should also add that I can't get the JavaScript or Python ones working as they rely on external librarys that aren't referenced anywhere in the [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=JavaScript#distance)!.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm also having trouble finding working examples of MapBox's distance API. Even the distance API link on MapBox's website seems to go to the generic documentaion: https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/distance/

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can provide a list of 2 or more semi-colon separated coordinates:

https://api.mapbox.com/optimized-trips/v1/mapbox/driving/13.41894,52.50055;14.10293,52.50055?access_token=pk.your_token

returns:

```
{
    "code":"Ok",
    "waypoints":[
        {"distance":9.0352511932471,"name":"","location":[13.418991,52.500625],"waypoint_index":0,"trips_index":0},
        {"distance":91.0575241567836,"name":"Berliner Chaussee","location":[14.103096,52.499738],"waypoint_index":1,"trips_index":0}
    ],
    "trips":   
      [
        {"geometry":"}_m_Iu{{pA}ZuQ}Iad@}cAk^jr@etOdE_iGtTqoAxBkoGnOkiCjR_s@wJ_v@b@}aN|aBogRyVucBiEw_C~r@_eB`Fc`NtP_bAshBorHa@}dCkOe~AmPmrGlPlrGjOd~A`@|dCrhBnrHuP~aAaFb`N_s@~dBhEv_CxVtcBkbBbeRo@l`NzJ`z@mRpr@qOpjCwBpnGoT~lAeEdkGsr@jtOtp@dQ~UjTtDfZf]jS",
        "legs":[
            {"summary":"","weight":4198.3,"duration":3426.4,"steps":[],"distance":49487},
            {"summary":"","weight":7577.8,"duration":3501.3,"steps":[],"distance":49479.7}
        ],
        "weight_name":"routability",
        "weight":11776.1,
        "duration":6927.700000000001,
        "distance":98966.7}
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is better now, but I had to work through it right now and can give you this example

```
curl "https://api.mapbox.com/directions-matrix/v1/mapbox/driving/9.51416,54.47004;13.5096410,50.0716190;6.8614070,48.5206360;14.1304840,51.0856060?sources=0&access_token={token}"`
```

This will return the following json for driving durations. I made use of the sources attribute, which is my search lng/lat and all other points are places in my database.

```json
{
  "code": "Ok",
  "durations": [
    [0.0, 29407.9, 34504.7, 24163.5]
  ],
  "destinations": [{
    "distance": 131.946157371,
    "name": "",
    "location": [9.514914, 54.468939]
  }, {
    "distance": 34.636975593,
    "name": "",
    "location": [13.509868, 50.071344]
  }, {
    "distance": 295.206928933,
    "name": "",
    "location": [6.863566, 48.52287]
  }, {
    "distance": 1186.975749670,
    "name": "",
    "location": [14.115694, 51.080408]
  }],
  "sources": [{
    "distance": 131.946157371,
    "name": "",
    "location": [9.514914, 54.468939]
  }]
}
```

Adding the `annotations=distance` parameter to the url will return the distances instead of the durations if you need that.

```json
{
  "code": "Ok",
  "distances": [
    [0.0, 738127.3, 902547.6, 616060.8] // distances in meters
  ],
  "destinations": [{ // destinations including the source
    "distance": 131.946157371, // result 0
    "name": "",
    "location": [9.514914, 54.468939]
  }, {
    "distance": 34.636975593, // result 1
    "name": "",
    "location": [13.509868, 50.071344]
  }, {
    "distance": 295.206928933, // result 2
    "name": "",
    "location": [6.863566, 48.52287]
  }, {
    "distance": 1186.975749670, // result 3
    "name": "",
    "location": [14.115694, 51.080408]
  }],
  "sources": [{ // source where we start from
    "distance": 131.946157371,
    "name": "",
    "location": [9.514914, 54.468939]
  }]
}
```